# Manipulating an embedded text file within Microsoft Office Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**Hello,**

I have to be able to read the content of a flat text file (.txt) which has been embedded in Microsoft Office Excel. (It has become accessible by double clicking on an icon.)

Accroding to my research on the web, it's stored as an OLEObject.
However, I couldn't find the way to access the data!

I noticed that when I double clic on the icon representing the text file, the latter was created in a temp folder that I could use. But, I want to be able to use that data programatically without having to double clic on the icon.

**I hope my descripton was clear enought, thank you for your consideration.**

Comment: have you tried recording a macro? does it give any clues to the code?